# Visio 2013 Keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-visio-2013

Can I have list of shortcuts for Visio 2013?

For example I am in ER diagramming mode and adding attributes for an entity how do I add new attribute for the entity?

As I can't find one right now I have to right click and say "Insert Attribute before/after", which is tedious job.

Answer (score 4):

I have been dragging the Attribute item from the Shapes window, which is even more cumbersome than your method.

Your comment about right-clicking to choose "Insert 'Attribute' After" got me thinking.

You can use the little menu key on your keyboard to open the menu. Once the menu is open, hit <kbd>n</kbd> to choose the "Insert 'Attribute' After" command. It will insert a new item and select it, then you can just start typing. Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> when finished and you are ready to insert the next attribute.

1. Select an Attribute
2. Press <kbd>Menu</kbd> on your keyboard
3. Press <kbd>n</kbd> to choose "Insert 'Attribute' After"
4. Start typing while the new Attribute is selected
5. Press <kbd>ESC</kbd> when finished, your attribute is selected again
6. Repeat

Comment: There's no "Insert Attribute After" command.

Answer (score 2):

The only list I have found is here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/keyboard-shortcuts-for-visio-HA102748913.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way to add new attributes is to select the bottom attribute in the entity, and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.